# Cannot start prometheus by using systemd

Tags: systemd, prometheus

OS level: `CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708`
Prometheus level: `2.4.2`
prometheus.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus

[Service]
User=prometheus
ExecStart=/usr/local/prometheus/prometheus

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

When I use `systemctl start prometheus` to start the prometheus service, it always exit the main process by itself. And the systemctl's log shows like this:

```
● prometheus.service - Prometheus
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-09-25 10:43:56 CST; 6s ago
  Process: 5174 ExecStart=/usr/local/prometheus/prometheus (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5174 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 25 10:43:56 devtestserver systemd[1]: Started Prometheus.
Sep 25 10:43:56 devtestserver systemd[1]: Starting Prometheus...
Sep 25 10:43:56 devtestserver prometheus[5174]: level=info ts=2018-09-25T02:43:56.736457704Z caller=main.go:238 msg="Starting Prometheus" version="(version=2.4.2, branch=HE...13b1190a0)"
Sep 25 10:43:56 devtestserver systemd[1]: prometheus.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 25 10:43:56 devtestserver systemd[1]: Unit prometheus.service entered failed state.
Sep 25 10:43:56 devtestserver systemd[1]: prometheus.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

I have no ideas with this problem. I use the same config for the `node_exporter`,  but `node_exporter` can start as normal. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You have not added configuration file i.e. prometheus.yml

Considering Service part of your prometheus.service file,

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/prometheus/prometheus \
--config.file /prometheus-2.26.0.linux-amd64/prometheus.yml
```

here, my .yml file is in /prometheus-2.26.0.linux-amd64/ location.
your might be different. Befre running check your both paths i.e. your executable file is on the path given in "ExecStart" and yml file is in --config.file

then reload your system by

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start prometheus
systemctl enable prometheus
```

then check the status using,

```
systemctl status prometheus
```

It should be active(running).

This should solve your problem. Let me know if it helped : )

Answer (score 2):

There is an extra "i" at the end of WantedBy=default.target.

To get more details about services failing to start, try sudo journalctl -ex

My guess is it's either the extra "i" or Prometheus might not be able to parse your scrape rules or alerts files. It comes with "promtool" to check your configuration files and is installed in the same directory as prometheus. Your first step should be to try "promtool check config /path/to/prometheus.yml"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can start the prometheus by command successfully. So I'm sure the config file is fine. From the systemctl log, it seems it first started up normally and then stopped itself very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue with Ubuntu 16.04. Turned out to be a permissions issue.
You should check that you user owns the directories in which you installed the binaries and the files inside these directories.

Comment: yes I also faced the same situation. What I did was make a different user and gave that user the permission to prometheus directories

Answer (score 0):

Where is the config file located? systemd is executed by `/` by default. prometheus reads the setting of `./prometheus.yml` by default. Perhaps you need to add the following config option to the unit file of systemd.

```
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus

[Service]
User=prometheus
ExecStart=/usr/local/prometheus/prometheus --config.file /path/to/your/config

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the key point is not the config file path. If I added it, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused because the data storage directory does not have permission. The default Prometheus data directory is /data.
chown -R prometheus:prometheus /data

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

copy and paste this in your command line:

```
sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service<<EOF
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus
Documentation=https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/overview/
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=prometheus
Group=prometheus
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP \$MAINPID
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/prometheus \
  --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
  --storage.tsdb.path=/var/lib/prometheus \
  --web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles \
  --web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries \
  --web.listen-address=0.0.0.0:9090 \
  --web.external-url=

SyslogIdentifier=prometheus
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran a few test running prometheus as a systemd service on ubuntu. It appears to require the following:

- that the location of the config file is specified
- that the location
  of the database is specified

Below is an example systemd service that appears to work on ubuntu:

```
[Unit]
Description=Prometheus

[Service]
User=prometheus
ExecStart=/prometheus/prometheus --config.file=/prometheus/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus/data

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
 --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus/data
```

where the `/prometheus` directory is owned by the `prometheus` user

But given [the answer of Emmanuel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63206112/4955266) it could be some permissions are denied by SELinux, I investigated this on AlmaLinux, an CentOS derivative, and sure enough the service failed to start with the following error

```
 prometheus.service - Prometheus
2        Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/prometheus.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
  1      Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-07-14 23:50:15 EDT; 36s ago
  2    Duration: 2ms
  3     Process: 11558 ExecStart=/prometheus/prometheus --config.file=/prometheus/prometheus.yml --storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus/data (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
  4    Main PID: 11558 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
  5         CPU: 1ms
  6 
  7 Jul 14 23:50:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Prometheus.
  8 Jul 14 23:50:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[11558]: prometheus.service: Failed to locate executable /prometheus/prometheus: Permission denied
  9 Jul 14 23:50:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[11558]: prometheus.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /prometheus/prometheus: Permission denied
 10 Jul 14 23:50:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: prometheus.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
 11 Jul 14 23:50:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: prometheus.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

After some more digging it seems [this is indeed due to a selinux security context](https://serverfault.com/questions/1006417/selinux-blocking-execution-in-systemd-unit).

It appears this command fixes it:
`chcon -t bin_t '/prometheus/prometheus'`

Answer (score -1):

I encountered similar issue in redhat/Centos.I solved it by temporarily running "sudo setenforce 0". You can also edit the /etc/selinux/config file and set the SELINUX to disabled

Comment: You should explain that doing this will also significantly decrease the overall security of their system. Disabling SELinux without understanding the consequences can be a very bad thing.

Comment: @DevenPhillips: Disabling SELINUX is a bad thing. Agree! but wondering if there is any other better solution than this? I tried setting it to "permissive", but that also didn't worked out.

Comment: @Ankit Agarwal: Sorry for the late reply - audit2allow may be of some help to you. See [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-fixing_problems-allowing_access_audit2allow) for more details.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal sorry for the super late reply; it appears simply changing the security context of just the file in question is enough
this can be done with `chcon -t bin_t /path/to/binary`